# Capturing Command Output Based on String

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I found this script and I am trying to use it to find an AD account by searching the membership of groups like so:

```
ForEach ($Group in (Get-ADGroup -Filter * -searchbase "dc=acme,dc=local"))  
{ 
    $output = Get-ADGroupMember $Group | Select @{Label="Group";Expression={$Group.Name}},Name,SamAccountName
}
```

I have no idea how I would put an if statement to this code. If there is a better way to accomplish the same thing, please advise. The main goal is to search AD groups for a username and return the group name the specified user is a member of.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is fairly vague; it would be better if you could explain exactly what you want the ***if*** to accomplish. Even better would be to provide pseudocode illustrating your logic - which might very well lead you to your own solution to the problem. The pipeline in PowerShell is quite powerful; it is, however, not the be-all and end-all solution to every possible PowerShell problem.

Comment: Currently the script outputs the Group name and SamAccountName of the users, I would like to search this output for an account name and output only the group name if the user specified exists in that group.

Comment: In other words, you want to find the groups that a given user is in?

Comment: Yes, but I need to search through every possible group in all domains in order to get them all.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are new to PowerShell and ADDS scripting. It's vital you spend sometime going the all the freely available training and videos online via …

Search for beginner PowerShell on

- Microsoft Virtual Academy
- TechNet Virtual Labs
- YouTube
- MS Channel9

… in order to get a solid baseline. Also, though a bit dated, but still recommended, pick up and use a copy of PowerShell in a Month of Lunches by Don Jones.

There are lots of existing samples even fully pre-built scripts of exactly how to so this all over the web. The MS PowerShellGallery should be your starting point.

```
Get the group membership of a given AD group and return a user-specified list of attributes to a CSV file.

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/getADGroupMembershipWithProperties/1.1/DisplayScript
```

You can also just use the ADDS cmdlets directly. No if statement required.
This is shown in the built-in PowerShell help file via the text there and examples provided in the help files. It's just a matter of filtering for the name

Just using the built-in stuff.

```
Clear-Host
$TargetUsername = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a username'
"Getting groups for user $TargetUsername"
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $TargetUsername | 
Select-Object -Property  @{Name = 'GroupName';Expression = {$_.Name}},SamAccountName | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
```

If you want to get nested groups, more code is needed. The built-in cmdlet does not show nested or indirect groups.

Comment: The Don Jones book has been updated; the title to look for now should be ***Learn PowerShell Scripting in a Month of Lunches***, and covers the material that used to be in ***Learn PowerShell in a Month of Lunches***, ***Learn PowerShell 3 in a Month of Lunches***, and ***Learn PowerShell Toolmaking in a Month of Lunches***, plus updates to at least PowerShell 4, and possibly PowerShell 5. I don't believe it covers PowerShell 6/PowerShell Core yet.

Comment: Well, that does happen, but since I got mine a looong time ago, well, you know.

Comment: Wasn't intended as criticism, just informational... :)

Comment: 8^} and wasn't taken that way.